# Connect to device on different subnet

Tags: networking, network-shares, home-networking

I have a main router(routerA) 192.168.1.1
3 routers connected with static ip 1.200,1.201,1.202
Each has dhcp server function on. In one of those routers a NAS with plex server is installed 192.168.0.222. how to connect a device which is in another router to this NAS

Comment: In short: add a route in the routing table. And try to phrase your question better so it is understandable

Comment: Sorry,  In the main router or the one with the nas connected

Comment: Please take a look at [Routing Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table). Also there is a good explanation [here](http://www.think-like-a-computer.com/2011/08/24/the-routing-table/)

Answer (score 0):

How (if) you can do it depends on the setup of the routers - from the sound of it, these routers are set up in a broken config, otherwise this would just work.

The first thing to determine is if the LAN interfaces on the child routers all have different subnets - which they should, but I'm guessing don't. If they have the same (or overlapping) subnet you need to fix this or use NAT port forwarding.

If they don't share the same subnet - or if you can change them so this is do -you should (a) program the routes behind each child router in the parent router (192.168.3.1) and (b) turn off NAT in the child routers. This will fix your problem and remove "double NAT" issues from your network.

If you are stuck with broken router configs, you need to go into the child router the NAS connects to and port forward all the relevant ports to the. NAS, or configure the NAS as the DMZ.  You then need to instruct computers on networks other then the one the NAS is on to look to the router attached to the NAS's external address to access the NAS.